# Erro o acessar o projeto no laravel4

Tags: laravel-4

Estou recebendo um erro ao acessar o projeto no laravel4. 
Estava funcionando, mas quando reiniciei meu computador e tentei acessar novamente. Recebo o seguinte erro:

> ErrorException 
>       unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 197 bytes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Já tive um erro parecido, quando tentei acessar a aplicação após trocar a "key" nas configurações.

Por isso todo projeto que inicio, gero a "key",e no arquivo
"app/config/session.php" altero a chave "cookie" para "onomedoprojeto_session".

Espero ter ajudado.